# How to I pass Vector.<> from Flash with ExternalInterface

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, externalinterface

I have a custom container (C#) for the Flash ActiveX control and am passing data back and forth.  Previously I would use ExternalInterface.call and pass an Array as a parameter. I would prefer to use the Vector class now that it is available, but it appears that when I do that the call is never made.

It *is* however made if it is embedded in IE. It appears that when in IE, Flash will send out JavaScript to execute rather than serializing to XML. My guess is that the Vector XML serialization isn't baked in, so Flash just ignores the call.

Anyone have any ideas? Other than just going back to using Array, I've already done that for now.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb2.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7caf) note that:

> Other built-in or custom classes - 
>   ActionScript encodes other objects as
>   null or as an empty object. In either
>   case any property values are lost.

It's not completely clear what that means, since custom classes are also Objects - I guess only vanilla objects count? But at any rate it looks like Vector falls into that "other built-in classes" category, so you'll need to either use Array, or re-cast to Array before you pass the data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use arrays with `[ArrayElementType("type")]` instead. or write a serialization function for `Vector`